# Codeigniter restrict to insert into other user's data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A user can submit his data, after login. There is two tables in mysql: items, categories. Categories has a field: user_id, but in item table, there isn't, every item should belongs to a category.

When a user submitting a category, its fine, i get the user id from session, and inserting it. 
When he submits an item, i set the category_id for it.

The problem is, the user can simply rewrite the category_id (javascript, on the frontend, click on a category : set the category_id), and submit the item into a category which is not related to him.

Two solutions what i'm thinking (but i haven't made like this):

**When the user inserts an item, i check the category relation, and if it's not the user's one, its exit.**

**Add the user_id field into the items table too** (not looking as a good option).

What is the good way or what's the proper/common solution in this case?

Comment: Let me get this straight you have 3 tables, users, items and categories. Specific users are only allowed specific categories and you want to make sure they don't put an item in the item table with a category they aren't allowed to use?

Comment: That's right, this is what i want! You defined it simpler! :)

Comment: then Wesley's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add the user_id field into the items table too

If you already have the user_id in the categories table, and you're certain that each item has a category, then this is unnecessary duplication, as you suspect.

> Check the category relation, and if it's not the user's one, its exit.

That's the way to do it - when you read the category id before inserting an item, make sure that category belongs to the user. Simple. I would probably just `show_404()`, but it's up to you if you want to show a meaningful error message.

Comment: Thanks! I will go on with this solution!

Comment: Adding the user_id to the items table wouldn't help anyways now that I think about it. When you insert a new one, you'd still need to check the category id and see if the user has rights to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a user_id column in category table. When user tries to submit entry check the user_id, if it is not that user redirect him wherever you want

Comment: There is a user_id column in categories table, but the user inserts data into items table only with a category_id.